# Unable to use Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data namespace in razor view

Tags: razor, namespaces, exchange-server

Since upgrading to Visual Studio 2013 I am no longer able reference the namespace Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data in one of my razor webpage views.  The Auth namespace will show, but the Data one will not.  Ultimately, I would like to pass an Exchange Contact object back to my view so that I can display the properties in the browser.  I am using version 2.2 of the Exchange Web Services API.  Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: I was able to resolve this by finding the assembly in the references section of my project, right-clicking and choosing properties, and make sure that the property Copy Local was set to True.